# How to get id of newly added child item in Python SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have these code written in Python using SQLAlchemy.

```
    dailyCashFlow = models.DailyCashFlow(day=day, cash_start_of_day = cash_start_of_day, cash_end_of_day =  cash_end_of_day)                                                                                                  
    branch.dailyCashFlow.append(dailyCashFlow)                                                                                                                                                                                
    db.session.commit()                                                                                                                                                                                                       

    result['result'] = True                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    result['message'] = string.join(['Daily cashflow saved successfully with ID=#'], `dailyCashFlow.id`)
```

The relationship is roughly : company->branches->dailyCashflow. 
I want to get the id of the newly inserted dailyCashFlow.id. I think I can easily refer back to dailyCashFlow object to get the id, but it's not. It use lazy='dynamic' set up in the model. Is that the reason? And, how can I easily get the id of the newly inserted data?

Comment: I don't understand when you say "I think I can easily refer back to dailyCashFlow object to get the id, but it's not." It's not what? If you do a `print dailyCashFlow.id` after the commit, what do you get?

Comment: It's not printing anything. Empty. None. I already knew that, if I create a company (top level model), after committing the database, I will get hold of a new id. But in this dailyCashFlow, I didn't get any. Hm.. maybe I got to recheck this :)

Comment: if dailyCashFlow has None for the primary key after the session is committed, then it wasn't inserted.   assuming you're accessing the primary key column normally and not peeking inside of `__dict__` or something like that.   are you sure "branch" is part of that same session and if so what do the mappings look like?

Comment: You're right zzzeeek! That is also my understanding, if you inspect closely this code, `string.join(['Daily cashflow saved successfully with ID=#'], ``dailyCashFlow.id``)`, you will see that the `]` is introduce too early. It should be like this : `string.join(['Daily cashflow saved successfully with ID=#', ``dailyCashFlow.id``)]`. Well, I guess now I get a good experience why unit test is a must.. :) - If you want moving your reply to question section, I would gladly accept it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I pasted my revelation to this questio

"You're right zzzeeek! That is also my understanding, if you inspect closely this code, string.join(['Daily cashflow saved successfully with ID=#'], `dailyCashFlow.id`), you will see that the ] is introduce too early. It should be like this : string.join(['Daily cashflow saved successfully with ID=#', `dailyCashFlow.id`)]. Well, I guess now I get a good experience why unit test is a must.. :) - If you want moving your reply to question section, I would gladly accept it as the accepted answer. "

So visitor to this page will know what did I do wrong ;)

Answer (score 1):

Do your mean is got id by inserted data?

```
result = tb_conn.insert().execute(data)
id = result.inserted_primary_key[0]
```

Comment: It is, but it's using the SQLAlchemy expression APIs, not the ORM declarative query API.

Comment: Aaah, pardon for my clueless answer.. Hm, but I want to use a simple declarative way. It seems like if I use expression API (which I haven't, as I am new in this field), I will not get much benefit. Or, maybe it's just my likeness ;)